# How to tell if PDO MySQL INSERT was successful with IGNORE

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert

I understand that I can simply `if ($PDO->execute()) { //true }` to see if a PDO INSERT was successful, but what if IGNORE is involved?

Eg.

`INSERT IGNORE INTO MyTable SET DateTime = CAST(:dateTime AS DATETIME)`

If the the record already exists, and so is ignored, will `->execute()` return `true` or `false`?

I can't seem to find any documentation which tells me.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` will always be successful, if the connection between PHP and MySQL doesn't break mid-way or something else happens which interferes with regular inner workings of MySQL. Since you mentioned only half of the problem (we don't know why you're using `IGNORE`), and you need to know whether there was such a record - why don't you use regular insert and catch the exception in case the record exists? Is this a batch insert in question?

Comment: @N.B. Thanks. I just discovered this myself. Also, to answer your question: The situation is inverted. I only wish to know if records WERE altered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->rowCount();
```

That will tell you how many rows were affected by the last query.

Comment: Is there an easy/quick way to figure out which rows were affected vs ignored? i.e. to not get 'JUST' the count, but an indication of which records were inserted vs ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this would garner me a quick answer, but it didn't, so I tested it myself:

If no records are altered as a result of the IGNORE statement, then `->execute()` still returns `true`. It will only return `false` if there's an error.

Comment: Yeah. I found that out. Ian Wood's answer above seems to yield the right insert count on an ignore.