# How do I correctly structure a PHP PDO INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Database tables are the same on both databases.  Just need to update 'table 2' with 'table 1' data.  Justly need to know how to correctly structure.

> Here are my fields.

```
order_history_id         
order_id       
order_status_id       
notify         
comment       
date_added
```

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Just put your sql query into pdo; You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304288/how-to-tell-if-pdo-mysql-insert-was-successful-with-ignore) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this,

```
SELECT A, B FROM TUser
UNION
IF EXISTS(SELECT dataUserId FROM TUserData WHERE DataId = @dataId AND UserId = @userId)
BEGIN
SELECT @dataUserId = dataUserId FROM TUserData WHERE DataId = @dataId AND UserId = @userId
SELECT A, B FROM TUser WHERE UserId =()
```